# Run the same code when 2 different events occur

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a big piece of code that's being executed when I click on a div element and I want the same code to be executed when I press the right arrow on the keyboard. I can't find a way to embed one event into the other.

So is it possible all of this code to be written only once and not twice for the different events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. Just bind two event handlers.

```
$('#myDiv').click(myFunction);
$('#myDiv').keyPress(keyPressHandle);

function myFunction(e) {
    //Your "Big piece of code"
}

function keyPressHandle(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
         case 39: // right
         myFunction(e);
         break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use an if statement that uses the "or" expression ||

```
if (click || keypress) {
do stuff
}
```

That's the basic syntax. You should be able to apply that to your code. Hope this helps.